# Which is the first CPU that Intel has added conditional move instructions to?

Tags: x86, instruction-set

I remember having read about it somewhere… Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings), Pentium Pro. They are suprizingly old, and I wonder why do you still need a switch for GCC to use them.

Comment: Thank you. Although Wikipedia is not Wiki. :-)

Comment: I also read somewhere that `gcc` doesn't use cmov instructions by default, but my `gcc` does.

Comment: Switch for GCC is needed because CMOV is quite limited in comparison to MOV. See what Linux kernel guys say: http://ondioline.org/mail/cmov-a-bad-idea-on-out-of-order-cpus

Comment: @gertas: yes you are right, I made a mistake. Sometimes I even need to add the optimization flag for it to use conditional moves.

Comment: I don't know how bad `CMOV`s are but I see ICC emits conditional moves very often. One can check it on https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @gertas your link is dead. on mobile here, can't offer replacement.

Answer (score 2):

CMOV was introduced with Pentium Pro (commonly called i686)